# Edit Rewrite URL in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: url-rewriting, sharepoint-2013

I am using `sharepoint 2013` version and hosted a site on `sharepoint` server.. I am using below `code` and saved in `index.htm` and make it `default` page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redirecting...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.yoururl.com">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Due to this, URL is only working when i type `http://www.yoururl.com/index.htm` i am looking it should work without `index.htm` .

Showing the below `error`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Fri, 31 Jan 2014 10:44:11 GMT
Connection: close
```

Any help or suggestion ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Url rewriting is a server side configuration. Depending on the hosting, you can or cannot infuence [rewrite urls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) engine. It is hardly possible to influence it from index.htm.